# Conditions for absorption

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence, markov-chains, martingales, kernels

Let $X$ be a Markov chain with countable state space $S$ and transition kernel $P$, and let $h \colon S \to [0,1]$ be a sub-harmonic or super-harmonic function. Assume that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$$ \forall x \in S : \ \varepsilon \leq h(x) \leq  1 - \varepsilon \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}^x [ | h(X_1 ) - h(x) | \geq \delta  ] \geq \delta .$$

Then I would like to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} h(X_k) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ almost surely. I think I can use martingale convergence to show that the limit exists and then somehow show that it cannot take values in $(0,1)$.

Comment: not every Markov chain is a martingale eg. Ornsteing-Uhlenbeck: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894836/is-every-markov-process-a-martingale-process, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730076/ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-markov-but-not-martingale

Comment: I would try to prove it by contradiction. I am guessing the harmonicity might come into play if we apply Markov inequality and then Jensen's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\de\delta$You were almost there.

Indeed, without loss of generality,  $h$ is sub-harmonic. So, $(Y_n)$ is a bounded submartingale, where $Y_n:=h(X_n)$. [So](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578497/submartingale-convergence-durrett-5-3-1), $Y_n\to Y$ (as $n\to\infty$) almost surely for some random variable $Y$ with values in $[0,1]$.

Take any real $\ep>0$. Then, by your displayed condition, for some real $\de>0$ and all $n$ such that $P(Y_n\in[\ep,1-\ep])>0$ we have
$$P(|Y_{n+1}-Y_n|\ge\de\,|\,Y_n\in[\ep,1-\ep])\ge\de$$
and hence
$$P(Y_n\in[\ep,1-\ep])\le\frac1\de\,P(|Y_{n+1}-Y_n|\ge\de)\to0,$$
since $Y_n\to Y$. So, $P(Y\in(\ep,1-\ep))=0$, for each real $\ep>0$.
So, $P(Y\in\{0,1\})=1$.
That is, $P(\lim_n h(X_n)\in\{0,1\})=1$.
$\quad\Box$